# Continuity of Lebesgue Integration

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be integrable over $E$.
>   (i)  If $\{E_n\}$ is an ascending countable collection of measurable subsets of $E$, then $\int_{\cup E_n} f=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{E_n}f $.
>   (ii) If $\{E_n\}$ is a descending countable collection of measurable subsets of $E$, then $\int_{\cap E_n} f = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{E_n} f$.

Let $E_0=\emptyset$.  Then let $F_n=E_n \setminus E_{n-1}$.  Now we have $E=\cup E_n=\cup F_n$ and $F_n$'s are disjoint measurable sets.  I wanted to apply the following theorem $\int_E f = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{F_n} f$.  However, I'm stuck on incorporating the continuity of measure into a proof about the continuity of integration.

I'm stuck on proving part (1) as part (2) will follow from taking complements of things from part (1).

Comment: You're missing a finiteness hypothesis in (ii). Consider $E_n = [n,\infty)$ with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @kahen: The finiteness hypothesis is that $f$ is integrable.

Comment: If you set $f_i = \chi_{E_i} f$, then $f_i \uparrow f$, so you can use monotone convergence (well this is if $f \geqslant 0$, otherwise use the trick $f = f_+ - f_-$ as usual).

Comment: @JonasMeyer Oh. I must've thought it said that $f$ was non-negative.

Comment: @uncookedfalcon I'm not sure how that proves the relationship between integrating over the union of the pieces of the set and the limit of integral of each piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose first that $f \geqslant 0$. Suppose we have $E_1 \subseteq E_2 \subseteq \ldots$ as in your question. Consider $\chi_{E_i} f$, we have $$\int_E \chi_{E_i} f = \int_{E_i} f$$(when I learned this stuff, this was the definition of integrating over a subspace). It's easy to see $\chi_{E_i} f \uparrow \chi_{\cup E_i} f$, so by Monotone Convergence we deduce $$\int_{\cup E_i} f = \int_E \chi_{\cup E_i} f = \lim_i \int_E \chi_{E_i} f = \lim_i \int_{E_i} f$$
For the general case, apply this argument to both $f_+, f_-$.