# Continuity of Integration (Lebesgue)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

On the theorem regarding continuity of integration:

Let $f$ be integrable over $E$.

If $\{E_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is an ascending countable collection of measurable subsets on $E$, then

$$\int_{\cup^{\infty}_{n=1} E_{n}} f = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{E_{n}} f,$$

I have seen a proof which used this result:

Let $f$ be integrable over $E$ and $\{E_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ a disjoint countable collection of measurable subsets of $E$ whise union is $E$, then

$$\int_{E} f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{E_{n}} f$$

by "disjoint-ifying" the ascending sequence $\{E_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$.

Now, to prove the continuity of integration, is it necessary to define the function $f$ in terms $f_n = f \chi_n$, where $\chi_n$ is the characteristic function on the union of the ascending sequence?

Comment: Which proof are you referring to? Without context it's hard to answer.

Comment: @AshwinIyengar This one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128406/continuity-of-integration

Comment: This proof did not define the function in terms of the characteristic function. But is there a need to do it?

Comment: This is too broad of a question.

Comment: @mathreadler I have revised my question for a clearer perspective in the problem.

Comment: This is also a different approach I think http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239662/continuity-of-lebesgue-integration

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this one, it seems that the answer is that there is no need to define $f$ in that way since the integral is taken not on the entire measurable set $E$.